# Material UI SpeedDial | How to customize ToolTips

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i use Speed Dial material Ui Component and i want to apply some style to the tooltips

```
  import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import SpeedDial from '@material-ui/lab/SpeedDial';
import SpeedDialIcon from '@material-ui/lab/SpeedDialIcon';
import SpeedDialAction from '@material-ui/lab/SpeedDialAction';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    tooltips : {
        backgroundColor : "red",
        width : 150

    }
}));

const actions = [
    { icon: <FileCopyIcon />, name: 'Copy' },
    { icon: <SaveIcon />, name: 'Ajouter Voiture' },
    { icon: <PrintIcon />, name: 'Print' },
    { icon: <ShareIcon />, name: 'Share' },
    { icon: <FavoriteIcon />, name: 'Like' },
];

export default function SpeedDialTooltipOpen() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
            <SpeedDial
                ariaLabel="SpeedDial tooltip example"
                className={classes.speedDial}
                hidden={hidden}
                icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
                onClose={handleClose}
                onOpen={handleOpen}
                open={open}
            >
                {actions.map((action) => (
                    <SpeedDialAction
                        TooltipClasses={classes.tooltips}
                        key={action.name}
                        icon={action.icon}
                        tooltipTitle={action.name}
                        tooltipOpen
                        onClick={handleClose}
                    />
                ))}
            </SpeedDial>
    );
}
```

in the material Ui docs suggest to use TooltipClasses props to pass styles to tooltip,

but this don't affect the SpeedDialAction tooltip styling

any help please ?

Comment: It will work if you remove `tooltipOpen `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally there is two way of doing this.

1. When you want your tooltip open along with your hovered item. If you go through material official [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/speed-dial-action/#speeddialaction-api). You need to add style for `staticTooltipLabel` . You can do this using like this. Keep in mind this works when `tooltipOpen`  is set to true.

Make sure add

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  staticTooltipLabel: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
}));

// then pass classes to classess

<SpeedDialAction
            key={action.name}
            icon={action.icon}
            tooltipTitle={action.name}
            onClick={handleClose}
            classes={classes}
            tooltipOpen
          />
```

If your `tooltipOpen` is not set default. Then your code works only you need to pass only `TooltipClasses={classes}`

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nexgi?file=/demo.js

Try removing `tooltipOpen`  to get how tooltip is working in material with `SpeedDial` component

Comment: thank you very much, so here we override default material ui styling ?

Comment: No we are adding custom class. `makeStyle` take care of it. If you see using `devtools` classess are like this:  `MuiSpeedDialAction-staticTooltipLabel makeStyles-staticTooltipLabel-3`

Answer (score 3):

If you, like in my case, want to avoid displaying multiline tooltip labels and others' solutions didn't work, this did the job for me.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        StaticTooltipLabel: {
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        maxWidth: "none",
      },
    /// speed dial stuff
}


//your stuff

<SpeedDialAction
     classes={{ staticTooltipLabel: styles.StaticTooltipLabel }}
     key={action.name}
     icon={action.icon}
     tooltipTitle={action.name}
     tooltipOpen
     onClick={handleClose}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The theme can be overridden so that the style changes are applied to all instances of SpeedDialAction. Since the tooltipOpen parameter is passed, you'll need to target staticTooltipLabel:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSpeedDialAction: {
      staticTooltipLabel: {
        backgroundColor : 'red',
        width : 150,
      },
    },
  },
});

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: thanks this is the only solution working for me